# How to identify current database while inside a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a simple stored procedure which will clear the contents of *some* tables in the current database - I'm doing this by matching a prefix against the list of tables in the information_schema:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure local_flush_cache(db varchar(255))
begin

select @str_sql:=concat('delete from ',group_concat(table_name))
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema=db and table_name like 'cache_%';

prepare stmt from @str_sql;

execute stmt;

drop prepare stmt;

end$$
delimiter ;
```

I would like to be able to remove the db parameter and have the function work on the currently active database.

I guess I will also need the ability to recognise that a database has not yet been selected and output an error (to prevent accidentally flushing all cache tables in all databases).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering that the procedure is tied to a database, the current is the called unless you do `CALL db.proc()`.

However, if you really want the selected one, you can [the `DATABASE()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_database):

```
where table_schema=database() and table_name like 'cache_%';
```

Comment: thanks - now I can get working on fixing my syntax error in the query I'm building ;)